# Any software that draws a focus effect like filter on top of the screen

Tags: linux, display, accessibility

From my personal experience, I found out that, it is easier to focus on display screen when border area is dark. That's why, I am looking for any software that can draw this kind of dark effects on Linux system.

If you used Gnome shell, it is kind of the screen where you type one liner command. I'm putting an example image here. [image]